# Error while trying to include Azure IoT SDK in ESP-IDF

Tags: esp32, azure-iot-sdk, esp-idf

Not able to integrate Azure IoT SDK in ESP-IDF

Hello guys, I am trying to use Azure IoT SDK with ESP-IDF.I follow the steps for this to that:

1. Download Azure IoT SDK from link: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-middleware-freertos
2. Then I pasted that file inside my C-drive.
3. Create a ESP32 Project and put location of Azure-IoT SDK in CMakeLists file

[image: Azure IoT]

But, during compilation I am getting an error. That means I am not able integrate that SDK with ESP-IDF. If any solution is there to include that SDK in ESP-IDF please tell me the procedure.

Comment: Can you confirm if you are trying to connect your ESP board to Azure IoT Central or Azure IoT Hub? There are some additional configurations that need to be set before you can build the code. Have you done that? For example, if you are trying to connect to Azure IoT Hub, refer the [Prepare the sample section](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-middleware-freertos-samples/tree/main/demos/projects/ESPRESSIF/esp32)

Comment: I just tried to include the Azure IoT SDK in my script. But, not able to do that for that I gave path of SDK in CMakeLists that you can see in picture and include a library link in main.c but it shows error.

Comment: Have you referenced the [building](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-middleware-freertos#building) section of the github repository? The build section mentions to use the add_subdirectory() CMake function in your CMakeLists.txt. Please refer the following [code snippet](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iot-middleware-freertos-samples/blob/be17acac1ef5d0c3d8d3f0539b0409dbcc69d0e7/CMakeLists.txt#L36-L42) shared from the sample.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are facing issues while integrating the Azure IoT SDK with ESP-IDF.

- You may check for dependencies installed for ESP-IDF and Azure IoT SDK and verify if we have included the Azure IoT SDK in your project's CMakeLists file.
- Ensure that your IDF_PATH and PATH variables are set correctly, and that your build environment matches the target architecture of your ESP32.

I would suggest you to follow the steps mentioned in the ["Connect an ESPRESSIF ESP-32 to Azure IoT Central quickstart](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-develop/quickstart-devkit-espressif-esp32-freertos.md)" guide.

*Use Azure IoT middleware for FreeRTOS to connect an ESPRESSIF ESP32-Azure IoT Kit device to Azure IoT and send telemetry.*